# Unable to install scikit-image

Tags: macos, numpy, scikit-image

I'm working on a Mac with python 2.7.
Whenever i'm trying to install scikit-image
Command used to install : `sudo pip install scikit-image`, i'm getting the below error :

```
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib>=1.3.1->scikit-image) (1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib>=1.3.1->scikit-image) (5.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=1.5.6 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib>=1.3.1->scikit-image) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: nose in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib>=1.3.1->scikit-image) (1.3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: futures in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib>=1.3.1->scikit-image) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib>=1.3.1->scikit-image) (3.4.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: backports_abc>=0.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib>=1.3.1->scikit-image) (0.5)
Installing collected packages: numpy, PyWavelets, scipy, six, decorator, networkx, scikit-image
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1
Cannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Comment: Your numpy-version is outdated and skimage needs something never (1.11). I'm not familiar with mac, but [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6331) talks a bit about your problem (although in some other context).

Comment: Thank you it worked. But after installation when i run the code, i still get the error :

`from skimage.filters import canny
ImportError: No module named skimage.filters
`

Comment: It is because `skimage.filters` does not have any function called `canny`. Use either `skimage.feature.canny` or `skimage.filters.apply_hysteresis_threshold`